# how to host wcf web service on iis wihtout using Visual studio

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I am not very much clear about web services. I have created a web service and hosted it on IIS using publish option in visual studio. Is there any way by which I can host my application on IIS (without using visual studio) only from IIS manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to use the publish function from within Visual Studio to deploy the service. Roughly what you need to do is:

1) Create the website in IIS Manager where you wish to host the service. Make sure your application pool is running the correct version of the .Net framework.

2) Copy your binaries to /bin relative to the root of your website.

3) Copy your web.config, .asmx, .svc and other needed files to your website root.